# Spring Boot Form Input Empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, freemarker

I'm trying to have Spring boot convert my form data into an Object representation (`ExampleInputForm`), but for some reason it doesn't seem to bind (`emailName` is always `null`). Am I missing something here?

### ExampleInputForm.java

```
public class ExampleInputForm {
    @NotNull
    public String emailName;


    public ExampleInputForm() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ExampleInputForm{" +
                "emailName='" + emailName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

### MyController.java

```
@Controller
class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/save")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> saveBrands(@Valid ExampleInputForm form, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        LOG.info("Saving brands: " + form);
        return ImmutableMap.of(
                "emailName", form.emailName,
        );
    }
}
```

### form.ftl

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <form name="input" action="/save" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" name="emailName">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show `import` part of file `ExampleInputForm.java`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add **getter/setter** for your **emailName** attribute to your ExampleInputForm class.

Comment: DOH! I was thinking it used reflection on class fields to bind :C Thank you!